# Add new property in subsonic partial class

Tags: subsonic

I added a new column(DateCreated) in a table(Activity) in sqlserver.
and I am using subsonic 2.0, how can I add this column as property in subsonic partial class, so that I can insert and update the value of "DateCreated" Column.
DateCreated will be provided by the user from the GUI.

following is the code I m using but it insert NULL & retrive NULL from the database.

```
public partial class ActivityInscription 
{

   public struct Columns
   {
        public static string IsInMixedList = @"IsInMixedList";
   }
   public bool? IsInMixedList
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

}
```

Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the column to the database then just rebuild the DAL. It will pick up the new column and add it to the subsonic DAL. There is no reason for a Partial class in your case. This will work providing that the table "Activity" is part of your subsonic list (includeTableList) of tables in the config file.

Comment: Yes you are correct. but what if we don't have source code. I have DLL & class in codegenerated folder.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution, I used and it  is working:

public partial class Activity
{

```
    public DateTime? DateCreated
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void BeforeInsert()
    {
        TableSchema.Table tblSchema = Schema;

        TableSchema.TableColumn ccDateCreated = new TableSchema.TableColumn(tblSchema);

            ccrDateCreated.ColumnName = "DateCreated";
            ccDateCreated.DataType = DbType.DateTime;
            ccDateCreated.MaxLength = 0;
            ccDateCreated.AutoIncrement = false;
            ccDateCreated.IsNullable = false;
            ccDateCreated.IsPrimaryKey = false;
            ccDateCreated.IsForeignKey = false;
            ccDateCreated.IsReadOnly = false;
            ccDateCreated.DefaultSetting = @"";
            ccDateCreated.ForeignKeyTableName = "";

        if (!tblSchema.Columns.Contains("DateCreated"))
        {
            tblSchema.Columns.Add(ccDateCreated); 
        }

        if (this.GetSchema().Columns.Contains("DateCreated"))
            this.SetColumnValue(Columns.DateCreated, DateCreated);

        base.BeforeInsert();
    }
```

}

Now it is working fine & inserting the values that I provide from the GUI.